# Entity Framework Z Plus Batch Update

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-plus

I am using Entity Framework Z Plus Batch Update method. I am unable to proceed due to below issue. Actually Update method works good when i give static values like `tagName="amir1"`. But I need to get the `Tagdescription` from a web service or from another collection based on the `tagId`, Update method is not accepting a extension method or any other method to accomplish my requirement.Its saying

> "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String GetTagDescription(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.".

Hope my requirement is clear now. Please guide me if there is any other approach for my requirement.

Here is my code:

```
using (var context = new TrialsDBEntities())
{
     context.tblTags.Where(x => (tagIdCollection.Contains(x.tagId))).
                Update(m => new tblTag { tagDescription = m.tagId.GetTagDescription(), tagName = "amir1" });
}

public static string GetTagDescription(this int i)
{
     return "test" + i;

     ///Replace above line with call to database or web service call 
     getting some text by giving i as input
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Write your code as follows:

```
using (var context = new TrialsDBEntities())
{
   var tagsToBeUpdated =  context.tblTags.Where(x => (tagIdCollection.Contains(x.tagId))).AsNoTracking().ToList();

   //Only use this code block if your tagsToBeUpdated list is too large
   Parallel.ForEach(tagsToBeUpdated, tagToBeUpdated =>
   {
      var tagDescription = GetTagDescription(tagToBeUpdated.tagId);
      tagToBeUpdated.tagDescription = tagDescription;
      context.Entry(tagToBeUpdated).State = EntityState.Modified;
   });

   //Only use this code block if your tagsToBeUpdated list is not too large
   foreach(var tagToBeUpdated in tagsToBeUpdated)
   {
      var tagDescription = GetTagDescription(tagToBeUpdated.tagId);
      tagToBeUpdated.tagDescription = tagDescription;
      context.Entry(tagToBeUpdated).State = EntityState.Modified;
   }

   context.SaveChanges();         
}

public static string GetTagDescription(int i)
{
     return "test" + i;

     ///Replace above line with call to database or web service call 
     //getting some text by giving i as input
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tanvir. This is Traditional Way. Will it have good performance? For performance only i am going to Z plus Entity framework.

Comment: Look at your error message! You cannot do that. From performance standpoint what's wrong? How many tag will be updated at a time?

Comment: I am going to save 50,000 records. I planned to call context.saveChanges once for 1000 records. So 50 batches.Hope that should be good.

Comment: Then use Parallel.Foreach(). I am updating my code.

Comment: tanvir, I have used the above approach and completed my work. One concern is I get threading issues when using Parallel.Forloop in entity framework. So better remove that code. I vote parallel for loop for non Database operations.

Comment: @jamir are your expecting Parrel.Foreach to be removed from the code?

Comment: Yes. Just leave it normal for loop. Normal for loop itself performing well.

Comment: Also worked fine for me, do we have a better way to do this today?

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

Unfortunately, that's not possible to use BatchUpdate with a value that changes from a row to another.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

In this situation, we normally recommend using our paid library that's build for this kind of situation and offer high-performance saving operation.

Example

```
// Easiest way
context.BulkSaveChanges();

// Fastest way
context.BulkUpdate(tags);
```

**EDIT: Answer comment**

> If I can't use updated row so why the signature of action is misleading and give me possibility to write like this: e => new Entity { Name = e.Name + "Edited" }

For most providers such as SQL Server, your expression is supported. You give a global expression so we can apply. Your expression doesn't doesn't change from a row to another, it's the same expression.

What is not supported is giving a specific expression from a row to another.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I found it already that your Bulk Update would help. Thanks for sharing your thoughts. But its paid library.  :(

Comment: Paid library must exist to allow to support free one ;)

Comment: If I can't use updated row so why the signature of action is misleading and give me possibility to write like this: `e => new Entity { Name = e.Name + "Edited" }`? You could use `Action<T>` instead `Func<T,T>`, aren't do?

Comment: @jamir for reference, NHibernate can use updated row: https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querylinq.html (go to chapter 18.6.2. Updating entities)

Comment: Does the paid EF Extensions library support bulk updates with rowlock? In my experience the free version always does a table lock so is useless in most cases.